# "Role discovery data is unavailable" when accessing Azure RoleEnvironment

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am using a WCF Service (which is a web role) and is interacting with the worker role. When I try to throttle between different instances of the worker role. It throws the following exception:

"Role discovery data is unavailable"

`RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyWorkerRole"]`

is not accessible in the WCF web service.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the setup you are using? Is this happening in Azure, or just on the local dev fabric?  When you say "different roles throttling", are you trying to get Role Data about one role from another role?  That error normally indicates that a polling operation was rejected at the network/transport level .. typically by the Azure Load Balancer .. due to port restrictions.  Wouldn't make sense if thats all in one role though.

Comment: Yes, that is basically communication from Web Role to Worker Role and yes I am running the application on the local fabric. I've tried different ports and have found out nothing so far. Kindly guide me on this...

Comment: My guess would be that the Windows Azure project isn't the startup project, and so you're not actually running under the Windows Azure compute emulator.  Is that possible?  Also, make sure you have an internal endpoint declared on the worker role.

Comment: wow, didn't even think of that.  Go with smarx's suggestion

Comment: It is the startup project, and yes I have created an internal end point and I am communicating through that end point... Still Stuck in this... :(

Comment: Can you debug and see what IS in Roles[]?  That may at least give you an idea of what "environment" its launching under

Comment: I've debugged the application and both the RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance and the RoleEnvironment.Roles are throwing "InvalidOperationException" in quick watch.

Comment: this would definitely indicate that whatever thread the debugger is hooked to is NOT running under the compute emulator.  If you woulnd't mind could you share your .sln and .ccproj file?  (I can provide an email if you'd prefer not to share on SO)

Comment: I got confused on the working of the Azure and implemented the WCF wrongly. This helped me out though...

Comment: [Azure Sample for WCF by Ryan and Steve](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/ch9/5/7/3/1/5/5/CloudCoverEp12_ch9.mp4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering to my own question to clarify a bit. I am new to Windows Azure and did not get the full concept of implementing WCF in Windows Azure and tried to add a simple WCF service using add new project and then wanted to add that WCF service by adding web reference of it in the web role (which is not the right way).

Watch this video, if you are experiencing problems with WCF and Azure and don't know in detail about the basics of Azure...

[Azure Walkthrough of WCF by Ryan and Steve](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/ch9/5/7/3/1/5/5/CloudCoverEp12_ch9.mp4)